# Agendar tarefa no Crontab pelo script.sh

Tags: linux, shell-script, cron

Quero agendar o `crontab` atráves de um `script.sh`.

Tentei adicionar a seguinte linha dentro do `script.sh`:

```
echo "00 01  * * *  retag    /retag/licenca.sh" >> /etc/crontab
```

Deu certo, porém ele **adiciona uma linha cada vez que o script roda**. Preciso que ele agende uma única vez e só.

Como resolver isto?

Preciso agendar esse arquivo em muitos lugares e com o mesmo horário, por isso a pergunta, queria uma forma de agilizar o processo.

Comment: Com o `>>` ele acrescenta a saída do comando no final do arquivo. Com o `>` ele reescreve o arquivo só com o conteúdo da saída do comando.

Comment: mas dai ele apaga tudo o que já tenho agendado correto? preciso colocar no final do arquivo sem substituir o que já tem!

Comment: o final sempre será `retag    /retag/licenca.sh`? Pelo que entendi você precisa que quando rodar o script se houver essa linha ele só altere o horário do agendamento e o restante do `/etc/crontab` permaneça intacto, seria isso?

Comment: Sim, o final sempre será retag /retag/licenca.sh ! Não gostaria que o script inserisse essa linha dentro do crontab a primeira vez que ele rodar, na segunda vez que o script rodar, se já tiver essa linha lá dentro ele não faz nada!

Comment: Do jeito que falei aí na pergunta ele tá funcionando, mas toda vez que o script executa ele adiciona essa linha de novo! Ou seja, se eu agendar ele para executar uma vez por dia durante 30 dias ele vai gerar 30 linhas dentro do crontab!

Comment: `sed -i 's/.*retag    \/retag\/licenca.sh/30 13  * * *  retag    \/retag\/licenca.sh/' /temp/crontab` faz um teste com esse comando... só altera o caminho para o arquivo no final, eu copiei o crontab para outro diretório para testar

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção mais simples é usar o `sed` no início do seu script, ele irá excluir as linhas já existentes no seu crontab, e assim que executar o `licenca.sh` com o `echo`, uma nova linha será criada no lugar.

```
sed '1d' /etc/crontab
echo "0 1  * * *  retag /retag/licenca.sh" >> /etc/crontab
```

No comando `sed` o 1 é referenciado a primeira linha do arquivo, o `d` serve para excluir essa linha, sempre em aspas simples.

Caso queira conhecer melhor o comando, utilize a [documentação](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed).

Answer (score 0):

Faz um teste simples antes, tipo:

```
grep -q licenca.sh /etc/crontab || echo "00 01 * * *  retag    /retag/licenca.sh" >> /etc/crontab
```

Se não encontrar a string "licenca.sh" no arquivo, adiciona.
Se encontrar, não faz nada.